# Install SSL Certificate for a DNS redirection

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, centos6, pound

We have an application developped on a internal server.
A DNS redirection to the livebox IP has been done for our customers to access a service online via OVH.
The online URL is client.lexcelera.com.

We have baught a SSL certificate for client.lexcelera.com but I don't know how to install it.

We are on a CentOs 6.4 OS with an AOL server.
We are using pound to set the ports.

Any idea how to install my certificate?

**Edit**

Here are the result of the host command:

```
[root@OpenMat ~]# host client.lexcelera.com
client.lexcelera.com has address 80.15.156.1
```

but when I try on 80.15.156.1 I get:

```
1.156.15.80.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lneuilly-657-1-25-1.w80-15.abo.wanadoo.fr.
```

Here is my pound.cfg:

```
User            "pound"
Group           "pound"
LogLevel        2

ListenHTTP
        Address 0.0.0.0
        Port    80
End

ListenHTTPS
        Address 0.0.0.0
        Port    443
        Cert    "/etc/pound/localhost.pem"
End

# By default show the "projop" production server
Service
        BackEnd
                Address 0.0.0.0
                Port    8000
                TimeOut 600
        End
End
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Pound, that is the application which accepts the initial HTTPS request and which must have the certificate configured or "installed". Check its [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pound) on the commands to use (HTTPS listener).